# Why is there Russian traffic in my web server's log files?

Tags: apache-httpd, logs, internet

My family's business runs a website with GoDaddy for promotional purposes. I checked the logs the other day and found some really strange traffic that I don't exactly understand:

```
188.234.248.201 - - [31/Jan/2019:10:22:26 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 241 "http://reduslimofficial.ru/about/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134"
185.127.17.253 - - [31/Jan/2019:10:23:15 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 237 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11"
216.244.66.244 - - [31/Jan/2019:11:06:44 -0700] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 301 251 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; DotBot/1.1; http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/dotbot, help@moz.com)"
178.137.89.36 - - [31/Jan/2019:11:37:03 -0700] "GET /index.php/about/ HTTP/1.1" 301 257 "https://videotop.biz/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; InfoPath.1"
178.137.89.36 - - [31/Jan/2019:11:37:03 -0700] "GET /index.php/about/ HTTP/1.1" 301 257 "https://videotop.biz/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; InfoPath.1"
178.137.89.36 - - [31/Jan/2019:11:37:04 -0700] "GET /index.php/about/ HTTP/1.1" 301 257 "https://videotop.biz/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; InfoPath.1"
178.137.89.36 - - [31/Jan/2019:11:37:04 -0700] "GET /index.php/about/ HTTP/1.1" 301 257 "https://videotop.biz/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; InfoPath.1"
178.137.89.36 - - [31/Jan/2019:11:37:05 -0700] "GET /index.php/about/ HTTP/1.1" 301 257 "https://videotop.biz/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; InfoPath.1"
178.137.89.36 - - [31/Jan/2019:11:37:05 -0700] "GET /index.php/about/ HTTP/1.1" 301 257 "https://videotop.biz/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; InfoPath.1"
34.73.100.219 - - [31/Jan/2019:11:40:15 -0700] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.0" 301 247 "-" "ZoominfoBot (zoominfobot at zoominfo dot com)"
34.73.100.219 - - [31/Jan/2019:11:40:15 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 301 237 "-" "ZoominfoBot (zoominfobot at zoominfo dot com)"
180.76.15.9 - - [31/Jan/2019:11:45:18 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 237 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
216.244.66.244 - - [31/Jan/2019:11:53:47 -0700] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 301 247 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; DotBot/1.1; http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/dotbot, help@moz.com)"
60.191.38.77 - - [31/Jan/2019:11:55:31 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 237 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"
159.138.5.222 - - [31/Jan/2019:12:01:57 -0700] "GET /administrator/ HTTP/1.0" 301 251 "http://www.alancoxonachip.com/wp-login.php" "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.12"
```

Some of this I understand, for instance, the ZoominfoBot seems like it's most likely just a crawler. Baidu I understand to be the Chinese Google, and I've seen Yandex, the Russian Google, index my site as well. But what are all these websites like "videotop.biz/" and "reduslimofficial.ru/about/". There is a significant amount of traffic that seems  to say "301" instaed of "200" and this causes me some concern.

One thought is that I don't understand the nature of the logs. That perhaps that's a referrer domain. The other possibility is that there's some malware on the server being used for a proxy.

Note: I am unsure what web server they use. I am pretty sure the OS is RHEL. But sshing into the server sandboxes me and `ps aux` provides very limited information. I strongly suspect, given the nature of the company, that it is apache (the 404 page does not say `nginx`, though I am unsure if that proves anything).

## ***So, my question is: why are there so many weird websites showing up in my family's (entirely local to Florida) business's website's server logs? What do the logs mean?***

Comment: I blocked pretty much all of the most know engines with mod_security., at least until I found out blocking Google impacted negatively my SEO ranking.  As for remote addresses visiting you there is not that much to understand, business as usual. Rest assured the KGB is not after your site.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro sorry for the clickbait title, lol. There's plenty of non-Russian traffic. It's just the `.ru`'s stand out to me.

Comment: But a script kiddy with warez to host might well be after a crack in your security.

Comment: Last time I implemented corporate VPNs I blocked out the entire IP address space of Russia, Africa, and China for a reason....loads of bots coming from there. Anyway, being in the Internet, it is pretty normal having bots knocking in your doors.

Comment: Alan Cox is on a chip, now?!?

Comment: I could write an answer offering some advice for Linux systems, as I handled servers with hundreds of vhosts in the past, but since we are talking about a Godaddy hosting service in which you do not even know the HTTP daemon, is even this on topic here?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro The question is really about what the logs are saying, not how to prevent Russian traffic. I wish I could ban entire regions of the world, but alas I cannot. The question is aimed at allaying my fear of malware (or initiating another round of "Please fix my server's security" with the GoDaddy support people)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro could you write some advices

Comment: I could, however not much use for someone who is using a service and not administering a server/Apache. Search here mod_security and mod_evasive, I have several answers dealing with that here in U&L too.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro mark it as a dupe to those answers and I'll say it solved my problem.

Comment: This is not a Unix or Linux question at all and should have been asked on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Rob It would have equally fit on https://serverfault.com/ for that matter. I chose U&L because I know the server is running Linux and it's a question about server logs.

Comment: Your question is about Russian traffic.

Comment: @Rob No, the question is about why random websites show up in http logs, not specifically Russian traffic. The title is click bait. Edit it if you like.

Comment: Your question is still only about traffic and nothing to do with Unix or Linux. That it appears in log files has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: @Rob If you understand the format of the log files to explain why there are websites foreign to my server's domain names, please answer the question. I'm pretty sure that the format of log files in web servers specific to *nix are, in fact, valid U&L questions. I see thousands of questions about [apache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache-httpd) and [nginx](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nginx).

Comment: @malan there are too many ways to interpret this question. None of them about Linux. *Is someone trying to hack you?* Yes. Every webserver on the internet will be attacked frequently. Hackers will pick a common insecurity and search the whole internet for an insecure server. You will get these attacks from all over the world. *What specific insecurity are they probing? Are they succeeding? How to protect against them?* I suggest asking such questions on serverfault.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That perhaps that's a referrer domain.

I think you've guessed correctly, assuming you're using the fairly common `combined` Apache log file format, in which case that field is the [`\"%{Referer}i\"`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html), which is fully under the control of the requesting client. Either it's the link that an actual human clicked into your site from or it's populated by the code in a crawler 'bot of some type.

Webmasters find the data useful to determine usage patterns of their sites and to know who might be linking to their site. If the data isn't helpful for your business, my advice would be to ignore it.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. That's exactly what I was asking.